# WPF Get Current selection in FlowDocumentScrollViewer into CommandParameter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, contextmenu, commandparameter

Trying to get selected text in a flow viewer to a command as a parameter

```
 <FlowDocumentScrollViewer Name="_OutputBox">
    <FlowDocument>
       <FlowDocument.ContextMenu >
           <ContextMenu>
               <MenuItem Header="New"
                  Command="{Binding AddDefaultTriggerCommand}" 
                  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=_OutputBox, Path=Selection}">
               </MenuItem>
           </ContextMenu>
       </FlowDocument.ContextMenu>
    </FlowDocument>
 </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

In the model class:

```
 private RelayCommand<System.Windows.Documents.TextSelection> _AddDefaultTriggerCommand;

 public ICommand AddDefaultTriggerCommand
 {
     get
     {
         ...
         this._AddDefaultTriggerCommand = new RelayCommand<TextSelection>(
                     AddDefaultTriggerCommandExecuted,...)
         ...
     }
 }
```

The problem is that in the parameter passed into the handler is **always null**:

```
 private void AddDefaultTriggerCommandExecuted(System.Windows.Documents.TextSelection parameter)...
```

Am I missing something? How does the standard windows Copy command get the selected text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because you didn't pass the parameter. Add a lambda expression and it should work:

```
this._AddDefaultTriggerCommand = new RelayCommand<TextSelection>(
                 param => AddDefaultTriggerCommandExecuted(param))
```

Comment: one more thing I came accross accidentally is that I had to add this line into Window ctor to get the context right:

   // Required in order to use the ElementName Binding in a context menu
    NameScope.SetNameScope(MainWndContextMenu, NameScope.GetNameScope(this));

combined, it worked perfectly, thanks!